# -ms-filter rounded corners CSS3 effect in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css

I am using -ms-filter to get shadow effects working in IE. Is there a filter that I can use for rounded corners in IE? I do not want to use htc files. Thanks!

Comment: Just extra files to manage. Also it breaks standards. I would like to isolate this with just CSS lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, I use htc file and it's ok but a bit limited, so I cannot round only one corner using htc file because it can curve all the four corners only. Also there're some other issues related with this htc file. By the way, the issues are fiexed little by little. And I've already added an issue and waiting when it will be fixed :)

You can check my test of rounded corners http://starikovs.com/2010/08/24/css3-rounded-corners/, in some examples the htc file for IE is used.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no "official" solution from Microsoft. You can find a list of `ms-` extensions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151008081039/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx).
There is hope though, as it seems like Microsoft will have `border-radius` support on [IE9](https://web.archive.org/web/20150522193954/http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Default.html).

Your options are:

- Use some sort of JS hack (see Sotiris' answer)
- Use a custom ms-border-radius hack, like [this one](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ms-border-radius/source)
- Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Out of these options I find the last one the cleanest. It also supports gradients and other cool CSS3 eye candy.

Comment: Yes, use PIE. Make sure you set up your server to cache the HTC.

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery. More information and different plugins [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/achieving_rounded_corners_in_internet_explorer_for_jquery_ui_with_dd_roundi/), [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/), [here](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/rounded-corners-in-internet-explorer/) and [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/82).

Comment: indeed a million jquery ways.. so don't need more thrown in my face. I am asking about ms-filter.